# moving marker does not exist on type of import

Tags: angular, leaflet, node-modules, openstreetmap, marker

moving marker does not exist on type of import please help me to solve this error.
I have installed npm package npm install --save leaflet-moving-marker
but it shows the error
**moving marker does not exist on type of import**

```
 // moving marker does not exist on type of import
    import * as L from 'leaflet';
    .....
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
       attribution: '&copy; <a 
    href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> 
     contributors'
     }).addTo(map);

     L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();
    var marker = marker.movingMarker([37.809185, -122.477351], {
         destinations: [
                {
                    latLng: [37.825766, -122.479218],
                    duration: 2000,
                },
                {
                    latLng: [37.831420, -122.479936],
                    duration: 3000
                },
                {
                    latLng: [37.832200, -122.480644],
                    duration: 1000
                }
            ],
          });
          marker.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you had only downloaded movingMarker but you have not added it to the script.

To add it to the script call:

```
import 'leaflet-moving-marker';
```

Comment: Failed to import that file shows error in index.ts file of 'leaflet-moving-marker';

Comment: What error you get? Have you added the import line after importing leaflet? Have `leaflet-moving-marker` typescript definitions or do you create them by your self?

Comment: Error: ./node_modules/leaflet-moving-marker/index.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: C:\Users\RAJATSINGLA\Desktop\Air-Pollution\leaflet\node_modules\leaflet-moving-marker\index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. 
Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library.

Comment: Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format 
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile

Comment: this the copy of error shown in above 2 comments